# Assigning name to Worksheet vs Sheet

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am using "documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.worksheet" in my application.

if I use Sheet, I am able to assign name to it as below.

```
var sheet = new Sheet();
sheet.Name = "XYZ";
```

If I use Worksheet, I am unable to assign name. How to assign name to worksheet ?

```
var worksheet = new Worksheet();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a example taken from the link below, easy to understand and use. This creates the file. Then creates the worksheet and later assigns a name to the worksheet, like this:

```
sheet.Name="ohyessheet";
```

Don't forget to add "WindowsBase" to the reference project. Also, add this using namespaces:

```
using DocumentFormat;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
```

This is the function to call to create the Excel file, but you just probably need the sheet info. Anyway, here is the complete example to create a file and create a sheet.

[How to: Create a spreadsheet document by providing a file name (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff478153%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(@".\MyExcelFile.xlsx");
```

And use the CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook to do the real work:

```
public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
    {
        // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
        // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
            Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
            AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
        {
            Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
                GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            SheetId = 1,
            Name = "mySheetNameISHere!"
        };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

        // Close the document.
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }
```